# AppMaker: example of a transaction

Tags: google-app-maker

My google search to find an example of a CloudSQL transaction code on AppMaker yielded 0 results.

Could somebody share an example please ?

REF: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example published on AppMaker site: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server#controlling_cloudsql_transactions

Comment: I totally missed this. Thanks & have a great day !